Gmail Firebase login API request failed
const userDetails = {
    displayName: user.displayName ?? `${input.firstname} ${input.lastname}`,
    email: user.email ?? '',
    photoURL: user.photoURL ?? '',
    user: {
      firstname: input.firstname,
      lastname: input.lastname,
    },
    mobile_number: input.mobile_number,  
  };

  localStorage.setItem('userDetails', JSON.stringify(userDetails));
  const response = await fetch('/api/proxy', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token || ''}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      endpoint: API_ENDPOINTS.FIREBASE_LOGIN,
      method: 'POST',
      body: payload,
    }),
  });

Context:
based on this code I got an error.
details:

"Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON" error
: "API request failed"

but when I used other env variables it works but the prod env are not working.
Please help.
We want to fix this with API response 200 OK when using this code with an env prod because this is working in a staging env or in a local env.
